# RabbitMQ Authentication with NTLM (password-less)

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, amqp, messagebroker

I have configured RabbitMQ but at the moment it is using simple username/password to connect to the queue. This isn't ideal as I'm having to store the password in the application config.

Ideally, I would like authentication to work like it does for an intranet application - using NTLM to implicitly pass my authentication to Rabbit.

I have enabled LDAP in the config which allows me to manage users in AD, but it still requires the password to be stored and sent.

Has anybody managed to get RabbitMQ authentication working with NTML (or Kerberos)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ does not support NTLM authentication at this time, as I noted in my response [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rabbitmq-users/m5EU2oWy8BY/kHlhkpRtDwAJ) on the `rabbitmq-users` mailing list.

Support could be added via a plugin, however.

Comment: Thanks Luke, appreciate the reply. I see there is a plugin for Kerberos, but that seems to also need the password from looking at the doc on github. I think cert auth is looking like the best option for us. Thanks.